# K-NN neighbours from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

This is a code I wrote last year for probability distribution of 
k-Nearest Neighbours in Matlab:

```
   function [ p_y_x ] = p_y_x_KNN(y, K )
    % Function calculates distribution p(y|x) for each class and each object 
    % from test dataset using KNN classifier
    % y - matrix of sorted class labels for training dataset N1xN2
    % K - number of nearest neighbors
    % p_y_x - probability matrix for object in X
    % each row of matrix represents distribution p(y|x)) N1xM

    % N1 - number of elements in testing dataset
    % N2 - number of elements in training dataset
    % M - number of classes

    N1 = size(y,1);
    M = length(unique(y));
    p_y_x = zeros(N1,M);
    N2 = size(y,2);
    for i=1:N1
        for j=1:M
            p_y_x(i,j) = (1/K)*sum(y(i, 1:K) == j);
        end
    end
    end
```

it works. Now I need to translate it to Python. I have this so far and I can't understand what's wrong with it. It won't work.

```
def p_y_x_knn(y, k):
    """
    Function calculates conditional probability p(y|x) for
    all classes and all objects from test set using KNN classifier
    :param y: matrix of sorted labels for training set N1xN2
    :param k: number of nearest neighbours
    :return: matrix of probabilities for objects X
    """
    N1, N2 = y.shape
    M = len(np.unique(y))
    p_y_x = np.zeros(shape=(N1, M))
    for i in range(1,N1):
        for j in range(1,M):
            p_y_x[i, j] = (1/k)*(np.sum(y[i,0:k] == j+1))
    return p_y_x
```

I can't paste the traceback, since this function is just a part of a bigger project and the only output I get is 'FAIL', not even 'ERROR' as per usual, where I could see what isn't working. The `y` matrix of sorted labels, just like everything else already supplied is correct. Maybe some of you could see any obvious mistakes in my reasoning?

**EDIT:**
Changed code:

```
N1, N2 = y.shape
M = len(np.unique(y))
p_y_x = np.zeros((N1, M))
for i in range(N1):
    for j in range(M):
        p_y_x[i, j] = (1.0/k)*(np.sum(y[i,0:k-1] == j))
return p_y_x
```

I changed ranges and k as @StackPlayer suggested, and I lost the 'j+1' since I believe, that one shouldn't be incremented. I'm still not getting any errors, just a 'fail'.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to adjust the 0:k to 0:k-1
and same for the for loops, use range the way it is (don't try to enforce the MATLAB 1-indexing onto the 0-indexing of Python!)

Comment: Thanks, I got confused with all the indexing... ok, so 0:k-1 and then I changed the ranges to (0, N1+1) and (0, M+1), is that right? Hope so. Right now though I'm getting an error instead of fail, "IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4" on the line with changed k's.

Comment: my best guess is simply use range(N1), best of luck!

Comment: ok, got it! now back to 'fail' at least, haha. thank you very much though, i'll do what i can! :)

Answer (score 1):

Stack Player said correctly. My addition for this answer is to use python3 with this function or change `(1/k)` to `(1.0/k)` and use python2.* Because in python2 `(1/k)`, where k is integer, returns  integer 0 and all elements are zeroes.

Ok, tests with this code on Python and your Matlab code gave me **same** results.

```
def p_y_x_knn(y, k):
    """
    Function calculates conditional probability p(y|x) for
    all classes and all objects from test set using KNN classifier
    :param y: matrix of sorted labels for training set N1xN2
    :param k: number of nearest neighbours
    :return: matrix of probabilities for objects X
    """
    N1, N2 = y.shape
    M = len(np.unique(y))
    p_y_x = np.zeros((N1, M))
    for i in range(N1):
        for j in range(M):
            p_y_x[i, j] = (1.0/k)*(np.sum(y[i,0:k] == j+1))
    return p_y_x
```

Comment: i'm using python2, so changed to 1.0/k, thank you! nothing changed yet but im all for improvement of the code.

Comment: So what error do you get now?) And it would be nice, if you show your current code

Comment: Sure, just edited to show! And I don't get any errors, just a fail as before, as if nothing changed :( I really don't know what's wrong anymore, I suppose it must be the function. I tried changing the np.sum to np.count_nonzero but it made no difference.

Comment: Write `p_y_x[i, j] = (1.0/k)*(np.sum(y[i,0:k] == j+1))` . Check it, please

Comment: checked it, still fail as before :/

Comment: It is really strange. I used Octave with your Matlab code and this python code: `p_y_x[i, j] = (1.0/k)*(np.sum(y[i,0:k] == j+1))`. I did some tests and got same results.

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong anymore. I've spent hours looking at this code now, trying out different things just to see if they work, and nothing does. It's driving me crazy. Thank you for all the help though, I'll keep looking. Can't really give this one up.